# Consolidating Table rows in Postgres/PostGis

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a table of weather data as follows:

Table Name: WindGrib

```
UGRD    -179    -90 2.9
VGRD    -179    -90 5.9
UGRD    -179    -89 1.6
VGRD    -179    -89 6.4
UGRD    -179    -88 -4.2
VGRD    -179    -88 11.3
UGRD    -179    -87 -4.6
VGRD    -179    -87 10.3
UGRD    -179    -86 -12.2
VGRD    -179    -86 13.1
```

UGRD and VGRD are at the same lon/lats in every case

The source for this data is a wgrib2 extract from a grib file and it looks like this:

```
"2013-10-21 00:00:00","2013-10-21 00:00:00","UGRD","planetary boundary layer",0,-90,-3
```

That is all we get ..

The date columns and the "planetary boundary layer" all have the same data.

I need to be able to move the above data into a new table as follows

New table Name: Wind

```
Geom(POINT,4326)    UGRD    VGRD
-179/-89            2.9     5.9
-179/-88            1.6     6.4
```

and so on

What PostGres/PostGis Query should I use?

Comment: You have what is called an [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_mode) which is notoriously difficult to query. Ideally there is another field, mostly for TimeStamp, or Observation number, which can be used to group the data in a query. It is missing in your Data(For example, how do we know that UGRD=2.9 & VGRID=5.9 belong together)?

Comment: @Devdatta Tengshe I assume, hopefully correctly, that the lat and lon will be unique and could be used to "group" the points. I have updated the question to show the source data from wgrib2

Comment: It might be helpful to confirm your assumptions by doing a SQL Query with Distinct. It might also be possible that your source data have multiple data at one Lat long for different timestamps.

Comment: Ran it and so far so good. Will keep an eye out for that, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I'm assuming your Table is built is like this:

`Create TABLE ObsData (Type Text, X smallint, Y smallint, Val real);`

Now you want to make a self join based on the X & Y Fields. Hence you should use a sql Join like this:

```
Select ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(a.X, a.Y), 4326) as geom,  a.Val as UGRD, b.Val as VGrid
from ObsData a 
inner Join ObsData b on a.X=b.X AND a.Y=b.Y
where a.Type='UGRD' AND b.Type='VGRD'
```

Here is a working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1c09d/1/0).

It might also be possible to do an Aggregate Query, Like this:

```
Select ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(a.X, a.Y), 4326) as geom,
    Max(Case When Type='UGRD' Then CAST (val as real) END) as UGRD,
    Max(Case When Type='VGRD' Then CAST (val as real) END) as VGRD
from ObsData
Group BY X, Y;
```

Do note that these kinds of queries are horrendously inefficient and might take some time. The query could be speed-ed up by using Indexes on the X & Y Fields.

If you are really concerned about Performance, and you should be only if you need to do this query repeatedly, you should have a look at the following questions on our sister sites:

- [Most performant SQL query needed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/9466/2752)
- [What is best performance for Retrieving MySQL EAV results as Relational Table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8764290/895)

Comment: worked like a charm ..

Comment: I would only put a ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(a.X, a.Y) as geom in the SELECT, since @Mark C wanted a geometry int result.

Answer (score 2):

The way I thought about your question was that I would need to separate the two sets of data (UGRD, VGRD) using somekind of subquerys of your original table:

```
SELECT
        ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon, lat), 4326) as geom
    FROM
        "WindGrib"
    WHERE
        name = "UGRD";
```

and

```
SELECT
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon, lat), 4326) as geom
FROM
    "WindGrib"
WHERE
    name = "VGRD";
```

Then, starting from one ot the sub-queries, I would need to join the other by their common field, in this case the 'geom', using the [ST_Equals()](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Equals.html) function like this:

```
WITH f as
    (SELECT
        ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon, lat), 4326) as geom,
        grib as grib
    FROM
        "WindGrib"
    WHERE
        name = "UGRD")
SELECT
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(g.lon, g.lat), 4326) as geom,
    f.grib as "UGRD"
    g.grib as "VGRD"
FROM
    "WindGrib" as g JOIN f ON ST_Equals(f.geom, g.geom)
WHERE
    g.name = "VGRD";
```

If you want to save the query result as a table, all you need to do is add the [CREATE TABLE AS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtableas.html) statement:

```
CREATE TABLE new_gribwind AS
WITH f as
    (SELECT
        ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon, lat), 4326) as geom,
        grib as grib
    FROM
        "WindGrib"
    WHERE
        name = "UGRD")
SELECT
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(g.lon, g.lat), 4326) as geom,
    f.grib as "UGRD"
    g.grib as "VGRD"
FROM
    "WindGrib" as g JOIN f ON ST_Equals(f.geom, g.geom)
WHERE
    g.name = "VGRD";
```

Give it a try and see if works.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Geometric Operations are usually much more resource Intensive that simple numeric comparisons. Hence the Efficiency could be increased by using Numeric equality, instead of `ST_Equals`

Comment: You are right, your answer is much better and cleaner. I will keep my answer just for the sake of the reasoning.